# Removing headset cups from 44mm head tube

Tags: tools, headset

I have a 2015 Salsa Colossal with a 44mm head tube.  The upper cup is a ZS44/28.6 (1 1/8") and the lower cup is EC44/33 (1 1/4").  I need to punch out the cups, so I bought a Park Tool RT-1.  It states that it works with 1" to 1 1/4" cups and Park's website explicitly says it works with ZS44 and EC44 cups.  The problem is that the flared part of the tool passes right through the lower 1 1/4" cup and barely catches the upper 1 1/8" cup.  I could direct the tool at one side and then the other, but I thought the main purpose of the tool is apply pressure evenly around the cup.  Should I have bought the bigger RT-2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The park tool RT-1 is the original headset cup removal tool for 1 1/8" headset cups.

[image: park tool RT-2]

The [RT-2 oversized headset removal tool](http://www.parktool.com/product/head-cup-remover-oversized-rt-2?category=Headset) is the correct tool for 1 1/4 and larger cup sizes.

That said, the RT-1 can be used, when directed carefully, on 1 1/4" cups also.

In my opinion, Park is too liberal in stating what larger headset sizes the RT-1 can work with, but it isn't technically wrong.

Recently manufactured RT-1 tools have more flare to the ends than the older RT-1 did, which may account for the difference as well.

Depending on when and where you bought yours, you may have the pre-1 1/4" version. Either because it's new/old stock, or because it was used...

Comment: I must have had older stock of the RT-1 with less flare (makes me think of Office Space!).  Park were nice enough to send me an RT-2 replacement (great customer service there).  That does the trick, though I feel like it's probably a little bit too much flare for a 44mm head tube to be honest.  Seems like the ideal tool is somewhere between the RT-1 and RT-2.

Comment: That often happens when the specs for a particle component fall on the edge of the specs for the tools. In this case either would work, but heather is perfect. :)